# Making a line in a table bold

Tags: tables, bold

Please consider the MWE below, this gives following table. Now I want to ladder-like line passing through the table to be in bold. Any ideas on how this can be done?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
 1 &  270 061 &  672 616 &  704 494 &  753 437 &  417 350 &  292 570 &  268  343 & 182 034 &  272 606 &  67 948 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{11-11} 
2 &  376 125 &  936 779 & 981 176 &  1 049 342 &  581 259 & 407 474 & 373 732 &  253 526 &  379 669 & 94633 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{10-10}
3 & 372 325 &  927 315 &  971 264 &  1 038 741 &  575 387 & 403 358 & 369 956 &250 965 & 375 833 & 93677 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{9-9}
4 & 366 724 &  913 365 &  956 652 & 1 023 114 & 566 731 & 397 289 & 364 391 & 247 190 & 370 179 & 92 268 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{8-8}
5 &  336 287 & 837 559 &  877 253 & 938 199 & 519 694 & 364 316 & 334 148 & 226 674 & 339 455 & 84 610 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{7-7}
6 &  353 798 &  881 171 & 922 933 & 987 052 &  546 756 & 383 286 & 351 547 & 238 477 & 357 131 & 89 016 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{6-6}
7 &  391 841 &  975 923 &  1 022 175 & 1 093 189 & 605 548 &424 501 & 389 349 & 264 120 &395 533 & 98 588 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{5-5}
8 &  469 647 &  1 169 707 &  1 225 143 &1 310 258 & 725 788 & 508 791 & 466 660 & 316 565 & 474 072 & 118 164 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{4-4}
9 & 390 560 &  972 733 & 1 018 834 & 1 089 616 &603 568 & 423 113 & 388 076 & 263 257 & 394 240 & 98 265 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
10 &  344 014 &856 803 & 897 410 & 959 756 & 531 635 & 372 687 & 341 825 & 231882 & 347 255 & 86555 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the reason? What do you want to show here? You should also right-align the numbers BTW.

Comment: The upper triangle represents observations, whereas the lower triangle represents estimates. I want to draw a clear line between them. The estimates relate to the chain ladder method.

Answer (score 4):

You can load the package `booktabs`, remove the vertical lines and use something like `\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){11-11}`.

Additinally you can also use the `S` column type defined by the `siunitx` package to format and align the numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\sisetup{table-format=6.0}
\begin{tabular}{rS*{3}{S[table-format=7.0]}*{6}{S}}
\toprule
 & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} & {10} \\ \midrule
 1 &  270061 &  672 616 &  704 494 &  753 437 &  417 350 &  292 570 &  268  343 & 182 034 &  272 606 &  67 948 \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){11-11} 
2 &  376125 &  936 779 & 981 176 &  1 049 342 &  581 259 & 407 474 & 373 732 &  253 526 &  379 669 & 94 633 \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){10-10}
3 & 372325 &  927 315 &  971 264 &  1 038 741 &  575 387 & 403 358 & 369 956 &250 965 & 375 833 & 93 677 \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){9-9}
4 & 366 724 &  913 365 &  956 652 & 1 023 114 & 566 731 & 397 289 & 364 391 & 247 190 & 370 179 & 92 268 \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){8-8}
5 &  336 287 & 837 559 &  877 253 & 938 199 & 519 694 & 364 316 & 334 148 & 226 674 & 339 455 & 84 610 \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){7-7}
6 &  353 798 &  881 171 & 922 933 & 987 052 &  546 756 & 383 286 & 351 547 & 238 477 & 357 131 & 89 016 \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){6-6}
7 &  391 841 &  975 923 &  1 022 175 & 1 093 189 & 605 548 &424 501 & 389 349 & 264 120 &395 533 & 98 588 \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){5-5}
8 &  469 647 &  1 169 707 &  1 225 143 &1 310 258 & 725 788 & 508 791 & 466 660 & 316 565 & 474 072 & 118 164 \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){4-4}
9 & 390 560 &  972 733 & 1 018 834 & 1 089 616 &603 568 & 423 113 & 388 076 & 263 257 & 394 240 & 98 265 \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){3-3}
10 &  344 014 &856 803 & 897 410 & 959 756 & 531 635 & 372 687 & 341 825 & 231 882 & 347 255 & 86 555 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the lines in the first column you can change the `\cmidrulewidth` to `\heavyrulewidth` inside the `table` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\sisetup{table-format=6.0}
\setlength\cmidrulewidth{\heavyrulewidth}
\begin{tabular}{rS*{3}{S[table-format=7.0]}*{6}{S}}
\toprule
 & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} & {10} \\ \midrule
 1 &  270061 &  672 616 &  704 494 &  753 437 &  417 350 &  292 570 &  268  343 & 182 034 &  272 606 &  67 948 \\ \cmidrule(lr){11-11} 
2 &  376125 &  936 779 & 981 176 &  1 049 342 &  581 259 & 407 474 & 373 732 &  253 526 &  379 669 & 94 633 \\ \cmidrule(lr){10-10}
3 & 372325 &  927 315 &  971 264 &  1 038 741 &  575 387 & 403 358 & 369 956 &250 965 & 375 833 & 93 677 \\ \cmidrule(lr){9-9}
4 & 366 724 &  913 365 &  956 652 & 1 023 114 & 566 731 & 397 289 & 364 391 & 247 190 & 370 179 & 92 268 \\ \cmidrule(lr){8-8}
5 &  336 287 & 837 559 &  877 253 & 938 199 & 519 694 & 364 316 & 334 148 & 226 674 & 339 455 & 84 610 \\ \cmidrule(lr){7-7}
6 &  353 798 &  881 171 & 922 933 & 987 052 &  546 756 & 383 286 & 351 547 & 238 477 & 357 131 & 89 016 \\ \cmidrule(lr){6-6}
7 &  391 841 &  975 923 &  1 022 175 & 1 093 189 & 605 548 &424 501 & 389 349 & 264 120 &395 533 & 98 588 \\ \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
8 &  469 647 &  1 169 707 &  1 225 143 &1 310 258 & 725 788 & 508 791 & 466 660 & 316 565 & 474 072 & 118 164 \\ \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
9 & 390 560 &  972 733 & 1 018 834 & 1 089 616 &603 568 & 423 113 & 388 076 & 263 257 & 394 240 & 98 265 \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
10 &  344 014 &856 803 & 897 410 & 959 756 & 531 635 & 372 687 & 341 825 & 231 882 & 347 255 & 86 555 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but I recommend to do the table setting definitely without the bottom lines in the first numbering column. If you really want to have the toprule and the bottomrule: keep it. I would do it without them, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that the standard fonts have a font series `b` (available only at fixed size, however) where digits have the same width as the medium size ones.

Note that alignment should be to the right in all columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\bn}[1]{{\fontseries{b}\selectfont#1}}
\newcommand{\tc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|*{11}{r|}}
\hline
& \tc{1} & \tc{2} & \tc{3} & \tc{4} & \tc{5} & \tc{6} & \tc{7} & \tc{8} & \tc{9} & \tc{10} \\ \hline
1  & 270 061 &   672 616 &   704 494 &   753 437 & 417 350 & 292 570 & 268 343 & 182 034 & 272 606 & \bn{67 948} \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{11-11} 
2  & 376 125 &   936 779 &   981 176 & 1 049 342 & 581 259 & 407 474 & 373 732 & 253 526 & \bn{379 669} &  94 633 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{10-10}
3  & 372 325 &   927 315 &   971 264 & 1 038 741 & 575 387 & 403 358 & 369 956 & \bn{250 965} & 375 833 &  93 677 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{9-9}
4  & 366 724 &   913 365 &   956 652 & 1 023 114 & 566 731 & 397 289 & \bn{364 391} & 247 190 & 370 179 &  92 268 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{8-8}
5  & 336 287 &   837 559 &   877 253 &   938 199 & 519 694 & \bn{364 316} & 334 148 & 226 674 & 339 455 &  84 610 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{7-7}
6  & 353 798 &   881 171 &   922 933 &   987 052 & \bn{546 756} & 383 286 & 351 547 & 238 477 & 357 131 &  89 016 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{6-6}
7  & 391 841 &   975 923 & 1 022 175 & \bn{1 093 189} & 605 548 & 424 501 & 389 349 & 264 120 & 395 533 &  98 588 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{5-5}
8  & 469 647 & 1 169 707 & \bn{1 225 143} & 1 310 258 & 725 788 & 508 791 & 466 660 & 316 565 & 474 072 & 118 164 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{4-4}
9  & 390 560 & \bn{972 733} & 1 018 834 & 1 089 616 & 603 568 & 423 113 & 388 076 & 263 257 & 394 240 &  98 265 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
10 & \bn{344 014} &   856 803 &   897 410 &   959 756 & 531 635 & 372 687 & 341 825 & 231 882 & 347 255 &  86 555 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `siunitx` and `booktabs`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

% a local command
\newcommand{\bn}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{%
    S[table-format=7.0,
      mode=text,
      text-rm=\fontseries{b}\selectfont
     ]}{#1}%
}

\centering

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{r *{10}{S[detect-weight,table-format=7.0]}}
\toprule
& {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} & {10} \\
\midrule
1  & 270 061 &   672 616 &   704 494 &   753 437 & 417 350 & 292 570 & 268 343 & 182 034 & 272 606 & \bn{67 948} \\ \cmidrule(lr){11-11} 
2  & 376 125 &   936 779 &   981 176 & 1 049 342 & 581 259 & 407 474 & 373 732 & 253 526 & \bn{379 669} &  94 633 \\ \cmidrule(lr){10-10}
3  & 372 325 &   927 315 &   971 264 & 1 038 741 & 575 387 & 403 358 & 369 956 & \bn{250 965} & 375 833 &  93 677 \\ \cmidrule(lr){9-9}
4  & 366 724 &   913 365 &   956 652 & 1 023 114 & 566 731 & 397 289 & \bn{364 391} & 247 190 & 370 179 &  92 268 \\ \cmidrule(lr){8-8}
5  & 336 287 &   837 559 &   877 253 &   938 199 & 519 694 & \bn{364 316} & 334 148 & 226 674 & 339 455 &  84 610 \\ \cmidrule(lr){7-7}
6  & 353 798 &   881 171 &   922 933 &   987 052 & \bn{546 756} & 383 286 & 351 547 & 238 477 & 357 131 &  89 016 \\ \cmidrule(lr){6-6}
7  & 391 841 &   975 923 & 1 022 175 & \bn{1 093 189} & 605 548 & 424 501 & 389 349 & 264 120 & 395 533 &  98 588 \\ \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
8  & 469 647 & 1 169 707 & \bn{1 225 143} & 1 310 258 & 725 788 & 508 791 & 466 660 & 316 565 & 474 072 & 118 164 \\ \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
9  & 390 560 & \bn{972 733} & 1 018 834 & 1 089 616 & 603 568 & 423 113 & 388 076 & 263 257 & 394 240 &  98 265 \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
10 & \bn{344 014} &   856 803 &   897 410 &   959 756 & 531 635 & 372 687 & 341 825 & 231 882 & 347 255 &  86 555 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Mindful of the saying "less is more", I suggest you *not* make the ladder line bold; instead, get rid of most vertical lines, and the ladder line will stand out nicely by itself.

I would also like to suggest you reduce the amount of horizontal whitespace (governed by the parameter `\tabcolsep`) but *increase* the amount of vertical whitespace (governed by the parameter `\extrarowheight`) in the table. I'd also say that using a full inter-word space as the thousands-separator for all numbers seems to provide too much whitespace; I suggest you use the `S` column type (provided by the `siunitx` package) for columns 2 thru 11, which will make LaTeX insert a "thin-space" as the thousands-separator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcommand\vv[1]{\multicolumn{1}{S|}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt} % more vertical whitespace
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}      % less horizontal whitespace
\sisetup{table-format=7.0} 
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{10}{S} @{}}
\toprule
&{1}&{2}&{3}&{4}&{5}&{6}&{7}&{8}&{9}&{10}\\
\midrule
1&270061&672616&704494&753437&417350&292570&268343&182034&272606&67948\\ \cline{11-11}
2&376125&936779&981176&1049342&581259&407474&373732&253526&\vv{379669}&94633\\ \cline{10-10}
3&372325&927315&971264&1038741&575387&403358&369956&\vv{250965}&375833&93677\\ \cline{9-9}
4&366724&913365&956652&1023114&566731&397289&\vv{364391}&247190&370179&92268\\ \cline{8-8}
5&336287&837559&877253&938199&519694&\vv{364316}&334148&226674&339455&84610\\ \cline{7-7}
6&353798&881171&922933&987052&\vv{546756}&383286&351547&238477&357131&89016\\ \cline{6-6}
7&391841&975923&1022175&\vv{1093189}&605548&424501&389349&264120&395533&98588\\ \cline{5-5}
8&469647&1169707&\vv{1225143}&1310258&725788&508791&466660&316565&474072&118164\\ \cline{4-4}
9&390560&\vv{972733}&1018834&1089616&603568&423113&388076&263257&394240&98265\\ \cline{3-3}
10&\vv{344014}&856803&897410&959756&531635&372687&341825&231882&347255&86555\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```